# Where to find interface designers on the internet?

Tags: interface-design, designers, work, wireframing

Just to say, I'm not about to make a pitch on this site for work. I assume that is probably against the rules of the site and respect that.

I just wondered if anyone has good ideas though on where to go on the internet to find good graphic designers that specialise in interface design.

I will shortly be building a web based interactive tool I will develop and need to find a developer to help assist me and the team in visualising our ideas.

I know many graphic designers that are great and making text look nice but very very few that are good with the more logical and technical thinking required for planning and executing detailed interactive software interfaces.

I've tried looking on freelancer.com and elance.com but found hardly anybody with the skills and kind of portfolio I was expecting.  I must say this shocked me a little as I didn't realise it was going to be so difficult to find someone.

Anyone with suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: dribbble.com is a good place to start.

Comment: Adding to DA01's comment, Dribble or Behance. Their search terms are much more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have my sympathies, this is a tricky thing.

A very similar question has been asked before: [How to hire a graphic designer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/how-to-hire-a-graphic-designer)

I would urge you: find someone local. Find the best you can, locally. Designing via email or even skype is a major hassle. It can be done, but I personally do not think it can be very efficient even if the people involved have know each other for years (believe me, i have tried every version of this).

I would suggest you read that other post, and then check out the [**Meetups**](http://www.meetup.com/) in your area.

I cannot stress "meet them in person" enough.

A few points:

- Find designs you like, and find out who did it.
- Collect samples of what you like, so you have something to show the
  designers; hinting at what direction you want to go.
- Go to a -say- designer Meetup in your area and talk to people
  (sometimes they let you present, and interested designers contact
  you. Plus: you meet them face to face).
- Find out how much you can pay. Not what you want to or would like to.
  The amount should hurt a little: great design does not come cheap. It
  simply does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search on [behance.net with GUI teg](https://www.behance.net/search?search=gui).

Sure elance, odesk, guru can help but you right that there tons of low quality stuff.
Best regards, Evgeniy.