# Need a short interview with professional for Graph Comm assignment

Tags: designers

Currently studying Graphic Communications and one of our assignments is to interview someone who already works in the field. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this might help? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/how-to-hire-a-graphic-designer

Comment: Welcome to GD.  This type of question is off-topic here since we are a Q&A format driven website.

Comment: If you become a member of our community, at least enough to earn I think 20 rep, you can come into the chat and ask us in there: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot

Comment: We've even discussed a chat session for this that could be referenced over time.